# Creating UserDefined Table type using (A) SQL Scripts VS (B) Creating Class in EF Migrations

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

We are using .NET Core and Entity Framework Core in our project.
I Need to create a User Defined Table Type which will be used as Input by a Stored Procedure.

One way is to add Migration file executing SQL Query to generate the Table Type and Stored Procedure.

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            var createTableType = @"CREATE TYPE [dbo].[temp_TableType] AS TABLE(
                [DateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                [Farm] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
             )";

            migrationBuilder.Sql(createTableType);
        }
```

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            var sp = @"EXEC(N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_DatabaseAppNetworkUsage_Nitro]
            @inputTable dbo.temp_TableType READONLY
            AS 
            UPDATE MainTable 
            SET 
            INSERT INTO MainTable(DateUTC, Farm)
            SELECT DateUTC, SUBSTRING(Farm, 0, CHARINDEX(''_'', Farm))
            FROM @inputTable T;
        }
```

Other way is to use the UserDefinedTableType
[image]
Link - [https://www.devcurry.com/2019/08/stored-procedures-udt-types-ef-core.html#:~:text=User%20Defined%20Table%20Types%20can%20be%20used%20as,that%20is%20to%20be%20passed%20to%20Stored%20Procedures](https://www.devcurry.com/2019/08/stored-procedures-udt-types-ef-core.html#:%7E:text=User%20Defined%20Table%20Types%20can%20be%20used%20as,that%20is%20to%20be%20passed%20to%20Stored%20Procedures).

Is there any advantage of using one over the other in case some updates need to be made or both are good.

NOTE - The TABLE TYPE NEEDS TO BE USED FOR STORED PROCEDURE ONLY.